# How to call a HTML select value in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the user's selected option value as a javaScript alert. But my alert is not working.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<select id="formats_id" name="aformats" >
    <option value="<?php echo $jrowa2['formats']; ?>" onchange="showshowFormat(this.value)" ><?php echo $jrowa2['formats']; ?></option>
        <?php foreach($formats3 as $v3){  ?>
            <?php if($v3 !== $jrowa2['formats']) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $v3; ?>"><?php echo $v3; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Here is my javaScript code.

```
function showshowFormat(){
    var $this = $(this); //  assign $(this) to $this
    var formats_value = $this.val();
    alert(formats_value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `onchange` with select:

**Pure JS**

```js
var showFormat = function(dd) {
  var opt = dd.options; //array of option of the select tag
  var i = dd.selectedIndex; // index of selected option
  alert(opt[i].value);
};
```

```html
<select id="formats_id" name="aformats" onchange='showFormat(this);'>
  <option>Text</option>
  <option>PDF</option>
  <option>Excel</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#formats_id').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="formats_id" name="aformats">
  <option>Text</option>
  <option>PDF</option>
  <option>Excel</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function showshowFormat(){
    var $this = $('#formats_id'); //  assign $('#formats_id') to $this
    var formats_value = $this.val();
    alert(formats_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
function showshowFormat(){
    var Getvalue= $('#formats_id'); 
    var formats_value = Getvalue.val();
    alert(formats_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load jQuery in your html, then try below codes:

```
<script>
$('#formats_id').change() {
    var $this = $(this); //  assign $(this) to $this
    var formats_value = $this.val();
    alert(formats_value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('#formats_id').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
});
```